# Sum of powers of variables

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer, and
$$
\begin{cases}
y_1+y_2+\ldots+y_n=x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n,\\
y_1^2+y_2^2+\ldots+y_n^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2,\\
y_1^3+y_2^3+\ldots+y_n^3=x_1^3+x_2^3+\ldots+x_n^3,\\
\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots,\\
y_1^n+y_2^n+\ldots+y_n^n=x_1^n+x_2^n+\ldots+x_n^n.
\end{cases}
$$

Is it true that then $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$ is a permutation of $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$?  How to prove it?

**Context:**
From comments:

--What did you try? How about $n=2,3$?

--Yes, I tried for $n=2$. It is true for $n=2$.

--For $n=3$: use
$$x^3_1+x^3_2+x^3_3=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^3−3(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)⋅(x_1+x_2+x_3)+
3x_1x_2x_3,$$

$$x^2_1+x^2_2+x^2_3=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2−2(x_1x_2+x_1x_2+x_2x_3),$$
same for $y$′s to show that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $y_1,y_2,y_3$ are roots of the same cubic equation.

Comment: What did you try? How about $n=2, 3$?

Comment: Yes, I tried for $n=2$. It is true for $n=2$.

Comment: You should include a description of what you tried and where you got stuck in the Question.

Comment: For $n=3$: use $$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^3-3(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)\cdot (x_1+x_2+x_3)+3x_1x_2x_3,$$ $$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2-2(x_1x_2+x_1x_2+x_2x_3),$$ same for $y'$s to show that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $y_1,y_2,y_3$ are roots of the same cubic equation.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true for every $n$. Suppose $x_1,...,x_n$ satisfy $x_1^j+...+x_n^j=a_j$ for $j=1,...,n$. We will find a monic polynomial of degree $n$, $f(x)=x^n-s_1x^{n-1}+s_2x^{n-2}-...$ whose roots are precisely $x_1,...,x_n$. We know that $s_i$ is the value of the $i$th elementary symmetric polynomial in $x_1,...,x_n$. So we know $s_1=a_1$. Then $s_2=\sum_{k\ne m} x_kx_m=(s_1^2-a_2)/2$. This gives $s_2$. Using $s_1^3$, $a_1,a_2, a_3$ allows us to compute $s_3$, etc.

Your condition shows that $y_1,...,y_n$ are roots of the same polynomial $f(x)$, so $(x_1,...,x_n)$ coincides with $(y_1,...,y_n)$ up to permutation.

Answer (score 0):

The key is using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)

Let $X, Y$ be the set of variables $x_i$ and $y_i$ respectively. Let $e_k(X)$ be the $k$-th degree elementary symmetric polynomial of the set of variables $X$. Let $p_k(X) = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^k$. We have that:
$$p_1(X) = e_1(X)\\
p_2(X) = e_1p_1(X) - 2e_2(X)\\
...\\
p_k(X) = (-1)^{k-1}e_k(X)+\sum_{i=k-n}^{k-1}e_{k-i}(X)p_i(X)$$
for $n\geq k \geq 1$

It's clear that $p_1(X) = p_1(Y)$ implies $e_1(X) = e_1(Y)$. Furthermore, if $e_i(X) = e_i(Y)$ and $p_i(X) = p_i(Y)$ for all $i < k$, then $e_k(X) = e_k(Y)$. By induction, we conclude that $e_k(X) = e_k(Y)$ for all possible $k$. Consequently, $X$ and $Y$ are the roots of the same polynomial, hence they are the same.